# setState will not rebuild

Tags: flutter

This is the build method of a stateful widget.
When i click the button i expect it to count up to 10. It does not. It only rebuilds when the number reaches 10. Why is that and what can i do to fix it?

```
int number = 0;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
                while(number < 10) {
                    setState(() {
                        number = number += 1;
                    });
                    sleep(Duration(milliseconds: 100));
                }
            },
            child: Text(number.toString()),
        ),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve by using Future.

```
int number = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            while (number < 10) {
              setState(() {
                number = number += 1;
              });
              await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100));
            }
          },
          child: Text(number.toString()),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```